# Derivatives and notation, and integral proof help.

Tags: calculus

I'm sorry if the LaTeX is translating right, I'm still new to this system.
I've been working on a generalized proof for $\int 1/f(x) \, dx$

I have three questions that I need to make sure I can answer correctly to ensure the quality of this proof.

1. Can I say that $dx/df(x) = 1/df(x)/dx = 1/f'(x)$?
2. Can I say that if $f(x) = y$ then $dx/dy = g(y)$ for all $f(x)$?
3. Because both $f(x)$, and $g(x)$ are functions of $x$, is $\int g(x) \, df(x)$ still $f(x)g(x)$, it seems to me like some information is lost if I do that.

If I'm right in these three things, then $$\int \frac 1 {f(x)} \, dx = \frac{\ln f(x)}{f(x)'} + \ln f(x)\frac{f(x)f(x)''}{f(x)'^3} + \frac 1 {f(x)'}$$

I can put out my whole proof, but I think it just weighs on these three assumptions.

Comment: Put a \ before things like `int` and `ln` to make them render correctly. For example `$\int \ln x \, dx$` renders as $\int \ln x \, dx$. Also use `\cdot` to show $\cdot$ for multiplication. More mathjax stuff can be found [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: Thank you, I didn't realize how unclear my questions were with the wrong formatting.  I had to fix a few things, but that helped a lot!

Answer (score 2):

1. Can I say that $f'(x) = 1\big/df(x)/dx$?

Not always. For this to be true in a neighborhood of a point $x$, $f$ has to be injective there.

2. Can I say that if $f(x) = y$, then $dx/dy = g(y)$ for all $f(x)$?

I am interpreting this question as asking if $f(x) = y$, then is $x$ a differentiable function of $y$ via the inverse of $f$? This is related to 1. in that you need $f$ to be injective in a neighborhood of $x$.

3. Because both $f$ and $g$ are functions of $x$, is $\int g\,df$ still $fg$?

You really have to be precise with the bounds of integration here. If $f$ and $g$ are both differentiable functions with integrable derivatives, then $\int_a^x g\,df$ is given by the integration by parts formula:
$$
\int_a^x g\,df = [f(x)g(x)-f(a)g(a)] - \int_a^x f\,dg,
$$
so it's not quite $fg$.

Also, your equation doesn't seem to hold if, for example, $f(x) = x^2$.

Comment: As an amateur mathematician, I'm not familiar with the word injective, what would be some good resources to look up on this subject?  Also, $/int f /dg$ really does the same for me as $/int g/df$. I was hoping to get around that be defining a variety of different functions.  I don't know if that is a thing I'm always allowed to do.

Comment: @TinyTim You should probably learn a bit about the basics of functions at somewhere like here: http://www.people.vcu.edu/~rhammack/BookOfProof/. Then you should consult a book in real analysis, such as "Understanding Analysis" by Stephen Abbott.

Comment: $f$ injective in a set $U$ means that for any $y, z \in U$ where $y \ne z$, then $f(y) \ne f(z)$, essentially that with two different inputs, $f$ does not have the same output.  To expand on point 1, you might be tempted to say it holds simply for $f'(x) \ne 0$ and argue that $f'(x) \ne 0$ at $x$ implies that $f$ is injective in a neighbourhood of $x$, but this last implication isn't true - finding a counterexample is a (not so) fun exercise in analysis.

Comment: @TinyTim despite the reputation of wikipedia it has some really outstanding math articles. it never hurts to type "injective functions" into google and look at the first couple pages

Comment: Why can't I just say $/Int /frac{1}{f(x)} /dx = /int /frac{1}{f(x)} /frac{/df(x)}{/df(x)} /dx = /int /frac{1}{f(x) /frac{/dx}{/f(x)} /df(x) = /int /frac{1}{f(x)f(x)'} = /frac{/ln{f(x)}{f(x)'}$?  I know this doesn't hold up, but given the appropriate injectivity, I don't know why this wouldn't work.

Comment: @TinyTim What does $df(x)/df(x)$ mean?

Comment: In my head, that was the derivative of some function with respect to itself, which is equal to one.  But it lets me change what I'm integrating with respect to.  Instead of I tegrating with respect to x, I can integrate with respect to the function of x.  It just adds an extra element to integrate over but wolfram alpha treats it as a constant.  My original solution above came from not treating it as a constant.

Comment: @TinyTim The reason this isn't a proof is because you have not defined *precisely* what it means to write $df(x)/df(x)$, nor proved any results about its algebraic manipulations that you would need to know are valid to make this a proof.